# how to use split function in both the side of condition in oracle

Tags: oracle, exists, split-function

Hi i have a table where the values like below

```
    user_country
    -------------
    210|9|211
    210|211
    9|87
    210|117|54
```

and i have a split function which split the data with the character '|' .
When user enters a value like 210|9 
the columns that contains both 210 and 9 values should be returned(i.e row 1 alone should be return).
I tried with multiple exists but couldn't get the actual answer

tried so far:

```
    SELECT 1
    FROM TABLE(split_text_fn('210|9', '|')) a
    WHERE EXISTS
       (SELECT 1
          FROM TABLE(split_text_fn('210|87', '|')) b
         WHERE     b.COLUMN_VALUE = a.COLUMN_VALUE
               AND EXISTS
                       (SELECT 1
                          FROM TABLE(split_text_fn('210|9', '|')) a1
                         WHERE a1.COLUMN_VALUE = b.COLUMN_VALUE))
```

Comment: Please post the code you have attempted.

Comment: would you consider normalize your db model? Multiple data in the same column isnt a good practice.

Comment: Also, please post needed result for that data

Comment: SELECT 1
        FROM   TABLE( split_text_fn ( '210|9' ,'|' ) ) a
        WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM   TABLE( split_text_fn ('210|87'  ,'|' ) ) b
               WHERE  b.column_value = a.column_value
        AND    EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM   TABLE( split_text_fn ( '210|9' ,'|' ) ) a1 
        WHERE  a1.column_value = b.column_value
        ))

Comment: What do you mean by "I have a split function"??  What "split function" do you have?

Comment: i have written a user defined function which split the data based on the character '|'

Comment: @manikandan Edit the question and add the query, don't throw it at us at the comments.

Comment: I need row1 210|9|211 alone as this has both 210 and 9 entered by the user

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure I understand, but... assuming your function will take a pipe-separated string and split it into however many tokens it contains, and assuming that the user inputs a pipe-separated string as a bind variable `:input`, and your base table is `table_1` with a column `user_country` and perhaps other columns, and you want to find all the rows in `table_1` where `user_country` contains all the tokens from `:input`:

```
select * 
from   table_1
where not exists ( select column_value from table(split_text_fn(:input, '|')) 
                   minus 
                   select column_value from table(split_text_fn(user_country))
                 )
;
```

This will probably take a lot of time - the price to pay for violating first normal form. You can have good performance, or you can have data in this very poor design, but not both.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I think you're after something like:

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT 1 user_id, '210|9|211' user_country FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 2 user_id, '210|211' user_country FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 3 user_id, '9|87' user_country FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 4 user_id, '210|117|54' user_country FROM dual),
-- end of mimicking a table containing your data; you wouldn't need the above subquery
-- as you would just select directly from your table instead
  vals_to_check AS (SELECT regexp_substr(:p_values_to_check_for, '[^'||:p_delimiter||']+', 1, LEVEL) val,
                           COUNT(DISTINCT regexp_substr(:p_values_to_check_for, '[^'||:p_delimiter||']+', 1, LEVEL)) OVER () cnt_vals
                    FROM   dual
                    CONNECT BY regexp_substr(:p_values_to_check_for, '[^'||:p_delimiter||']+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL)
SELECT yt.user_id,
       yt.user_country
FROM   your_table yt
       INNER JOIN vals_to_check vtc ON :p_delimiter||yt.user_country||:p_delimiter LIKE '%'||:p_delimiter||vtc.val||:p_delimiter||'%'
GROUP BY yt.user_id,
         yt.user_country,
         vtc.cnt_vals
HAVING   COUNT(*) = cnt_vals;
```

**Results:**

```
-- with the bind variables set to the following:
variable p_delimiter varchar2
variable p_values_to_check_for varchar2
exec :p_delimiter := '|'; :p_values_to_check_for := '210|9';

   USER_ID USER_COUNTRY
---------- ------------
         1 210|9|211

-- with the bind variables set to the following:
variable p_delimiter varchar2
variable p_values_to_check_for varchar2
exec :p_delimiter := '|'; :p_values_to_check_for := '210|211';

   USER_ID USER_COUNTRY
---------- ------------
         1 210|9|211
         2 210|211
```

N.B. I did the splitting of the input string directly in the sql - no need for a separate pl/sql function call. However, you may wish to continue using your split_text_fn function, in which case you can skip declaring the `vals_to_check` subquery and just use your `table(split_text_fn(...))` in the main SQL statement.